# NoReverseMatch error when making update form containing category slug

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a form that updates an existing Category and then redirects back to the Category page. Here is my code:

forms.py

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the category name.")
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=256, required=False, help_text="Please enter the description of the category.")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    status = forms.BooleanField(label='Status',
                               required=False, 
                               help_text="Is this category still active?")

    # An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Category
        fields = ('name', 'description', )
```

views.py

```
def update_category(request, category_name_slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_name_slug)
    form = CategoryForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
                        reverse('obj', kwargs={'category_name_slug':category_name_slug}) )
    return render(request, "courses/update_category.html", {'form': form})
```

update_category.html

```
{% block main_content %}
    <h1>Add a Category</h1>
    <form id="update_category_form" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Category" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

When I try to update using this form, I get a NoReverseMatch error. I have a feeling it has something to do with the views.py. How exactly do I write the first return? I managed to get another update form without a slug to work fine, so is it the slug that's causing the problem? Do I need pk/id? Thanks.

Edit: Here's the urls module:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.courses, name='courses'),
    url(r'^about/', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^add_category/$', views.add_category, name='add_category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/add_course/$', views.add_course, name='add_course'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/delete_category/$', views.delete_category, name='delete_category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/update_category/$', views.update_category, name='delete_category'),
```

]

Comment: Show your `urls.py`. I doubt `obj` is a pattern name.

Comment: The other update form I made was able to work with putting the object variable into the return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the url's pattern name of the *Category page* to `reverse`:

```
def update_category(request, category_name_slug):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
                        reverse('category', kwargs={'category_name_slug':category_name_slug}) )
```

Comment: Wow, that's something new that I really should know.

Comment: @JerryBi, this answer works very well, but you should also *learn* the [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method. It's more elegant and DRYer. Best regards to all!

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the line:

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('obj', ...)`

You're passing to [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) method, the string `'obj'` which is actually a `Category` object.

An elegant way to do it, is to add a [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method inside your `Category` model, like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    # model fields here

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category', kwargs={'category_name_slug': self.slug})
```

Then, in your `update_category` view, simply do:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(obj.get_absolute_url())
```